# Meteor router working in dev mode but not in production mode

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to protect an admin page, so I created a role for it. I'm using iron:router for the routes, and in production mode I have an issue: everytime I type the url/admin in my browser, I end up in /user (it's the login page). I don't have this issue in dev mode ! I really don't get why

Here is the code:

```
var middleware;

middleware = {
  isAdmin: function() {
    var user;
    user = Meteor.user();

    if (!Roles.userIsInRole(user, ['admin'])) {
      this.redirect('user');
      return;
    }

    return this.next();
  }
};
```

And for the router: (in

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('user', {
    path: '/user'
  });
  return this.route('admin', {
    path: '/admin',
    before: [middleware.isAdmin]
  });
});
```

Comment: offtopic, try `meteor run --production` in dev mode and see whether problem exists or not

Comment: Is it as simple as you not having the admin role set on the user account on your production server?

Comment: @tarmes , @ Sasikanth Yes I am testing with `$ meteor` for the dev mode, and `$ meteor run --production` for the production mode, and that is how I can tell there is a difference between the two

Comment: @tarmes no because when i click on a link to /admin from my website, it works ! It is only when i type url/admin by hand in my browser !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in fact I just used fast-render, which automatically solves my problem. Hope it'll help somebody !

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue previously. The problem is the delay in Meteor identifying you are a logged in user.

When navigating within the app, `Meteor.user()` remains set, so you can reach your route. When typing in the URL, you perform a full page refresh so the route hook is called before Meteor can finish logging you in.

Therefore, `user = Meteor.user();` will set `user` to `null` and you are redirected to the user page.

You can use `Meteor.loggingIn()` to check whether the login process is still ongoing. Iron Router's `waitOn` hook can be used for this (or just setting a timed delay will probably do the trick in most cases).

Comment: Thank you. I tried it before but didn't work. I had to use fast-render to solve my problem !